# List of strings in python

Tags: python

I have a csv file which has a column of dates and I m importing that using the below code.

Problem is when i map that to a list of strings, it is printed as below.

`["['05/06/2020']", "['1/6/2020']", "['5/22/2020']"]`

With this I'm unable to check if the list contains my value(eg: another date) after doing necessary formatting.

I would like this to be

`['05/06/2020', '1/6/2020', '5/22/2020']`

```py
with open('holidays.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_Reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_Reader)
    listDates = list(map(str,csv_Reader))

    print(listDates)
```

Comment: What is in the actual file? `listDates = list(csv_Reader)` would seem to be sufficient.

Comment: It has a single column of dates. Yes, I tried your line of code before using the map(str,)... But it returned me list of lists which i don't want as I had little difficulty checking whether the date inputted by the user is available in the list.

Comment: `listDates = [x[0] for x in csv_Reader]`?

Answer (score 3):

You can just simply add one extra line like so:

```
with open('holidays.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_Reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_Reader)
    listDates = list(map(str,csv_Reader))
    listDates = [x.split("'")[1] for x in listDates]

    print(listDates)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval` in a list comprehension to evaluate individual elements and capture the first entry:

```
import ast

lst = ["['05/06/2020']", "['1/6/2020']", "['5/22/2020']"]

res = [ast.literal_eval(x)[0] for x in lst]
# ['05/06/2020', '1/6/2020', '5/22/2020']
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
l = ["['05/06/2020']", "['1/6/2020']", "['5/22/2020']"]
l = [s[2:-2] for s in l]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['05/06/2020', '1/6/2020', '5/22/2020']
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file looks like this

```
05/06/2020
01/06/2020
05/22/2020
```

all you need is

```
with open('holidays.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_Reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_Reader)
    listDates = [row[0] for row in csv_Reader]
```

Each row will be a list of fields, even if there is only one field.